# Does this sequence of ratios of digit sums have a limit?

Tags: limits-and-convergence, integer-sequences, digits

I asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2438869/does-this-sequence-have-a-limit) question a few hours ago on MathStackExchange and there it received some attention but we still do not have a proof so I decided to ask it here also, in an unchanged form, and here it is:

Digit sums of numbers $3^m$ in base $10$ for $m=1,2,...,50$ are:

$3,9,9,9,9,18,18,18,27,27,27,18,27,45,36,27,27,45,36,45,27,45,54,54,63,63,81,72,72,63,81,63,72,99,81,81,90,90,81,90,99,90,108,90,99,108,126,117,108,144$.

Ratios $\dfrac {ds_{10}(3^m)}{ds_{10}(3^{m+1})}$ for $m=1,2,...,49$ to three decimal places are:

$0.333,1.000,1.000,1.000,0.500,1.000,1.000,0.666,1.000,1.000,1.500,0.666,0.600,1.250,1.333,1.000,0.600,1.250,0.800,1.666,0.600,0.833,1.000,0.857,1.000,0.777,1.125,1.000,1.142,0.777,1.285,0.875,0.727,1.222,1.000,0.900,1.000,1.111,0.900,0.909,1.100,0.833,1.200,0.909,0.916,0.857,1.076,1.083,0.750$

> Does there exist limit of the sequence $a(m)=\dfrac {ds_{10}(3^m)}{ds_{10}(3^{m+1})}$?

I cannot resist to note some kind of *chebyshevness* of this question (if there is one) because we know that Chebyshev proved that if limit in the prime number theorem exists then it must be equal to $1$. It could be that this is also the case here.

I also welcome any computational effort and results obtained from such an experimental work if the proof is out of reach.

Comment: The numbers are tabulated at http://oeis.org/A004166

Answer (score 4):

If the limit exists, it of course equals 1. Indeed, $A(m):=a(m)a(m+1)\dots a(2m-1)=ds_{10}(3^m)/ds_{10}(3^{2m})\in [\frac1{9m},9m]$. But if $\lim a(m)\ne 1$, then $A(m)$ is either exponentially large or exponentially small for large $m$.

Probabilistic speculations suggest that that $ds_{10}(3^m)=(\frac92 \log_{10} 3+o(1))m$, that would imply that your limit equals 1. But I am afraid that it is too hard to prove.

Comment: I think there is a recent ArXiv post by David Radcliffe on digit sums which might resolve this.  I'll check it out and report back.  Gerhard "From The IRC #Math Days" Paseman, 2017.09.21.

Comment: Is ir reasonable to expect that there will appear some fluctuations that will prevent the existence of limit?

Comment: if the digits are less or more random, than the expectation of having too large or too small sum of digits is exponentially small in $m^2$. Since such a series converges very quickly, Borel--Cantelli heuristics says that we should expect this limit to exist.

Answer (score 3):

Experimentally, the sequence converges to $1,$ at the logarithmic rate suggested in Fedor's answer. Here is the graph for the first 20000 numbers:

[image]

Now, when we fit the actual $ds_{10}(3^m),$ we get the following suggestive graph:

[image]

Whose slope is pretty close to Fedor's "probabilistic" value. *HOWEVER* convergence is slow - empirically, Fedor's $o(1)$ term is actually of order $1/\log m.$